# Nested where clause, except operator asking for right parenthesis

Tags: sql

I'm getting an error saying that the right parenthesis is missing. It wants me to close my not exists statement within my where clause first before using the except operator

my code:

```
select S.ID, S.SNAME
from ENROLLMENT E, STUDENT S
where E.STUDENT = S.ID and E.COURSENUM = 310 and E.DEPT = 'MATH'
intersect
select S2.ID, S2.SNAME
from STUDENT S2
where not exists(
    select P.PCOURSENUM, P.DEPT
    from PREREQUISITE P
    where P.COURSENUM = 310 and P.DEPT = 'MATH'
    except
    select T.COURSENUM, T.DEPT
    from TRANSCRIPT T
    where T.STUDENT = S2.ID
)
```

Comment: You open two parenthesis here: `where not exists(
(` remove one

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: the two parenthesis was an typo when copying the code over.

Comment: So your code didn't have that?

Comment: I edited my question to remove the typo. I had double parentheses by accident. My code has the single pair of parenthesis. though I have tried several different ways of adding more parenthesis around different sections of the code to try and fix the problem, this is my original code.

Comment: I see no error in your query. Maybe it's a flaw in your DBMS. What DBMS are you using? You haven't tagged it.

Comment: Oracle's SQL*Plus. And that's the only thing I can figure, which is infuriating. Thanks. So long as I'm not crazy